# Switch and persist selected tab of ng2-bootstrap <tabset>, <tab> using Angular router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ng2-bootstrap, angular2-router

I have a component showing tabs using [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/tabs) `tabset` and `tab`.

Example:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Info" [active]="tabs[0].active">
        <account-data *ngIf="tabs[0].active"></account-data>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Users" [active]="tabs[1].active">
        <manage-users *ngIf="tabs[1].active"></manage-users>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Billing" [active]="tabs[2].active">
        <account-billing *ngIf="tabs[2].active"></account-billing>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Note: `tabs[N].active` is controlled by the component and already syncs tab-changes and routes. But I have the feeling that I'm doing it the wrong way, because it's hard to manage routing inside the selected tab. Let's take the second tab, at the end of the day it should manage following sub-routes:

```
.../users          -> provide list of users
.../users/new      -> create new user
.../users/:id      -> show a particular user
.../users/:id/edit -> edit a particular user
```

It's not easy, because the component showing the tabs already uses this route:

```
.../:tab
```

It'd be way easier if there was something like this:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Info" [routerLink]="['info']"></tab>
    <tab heading="Users" [routerLink]="['users']"></tab>
    <tab heading="Billing" [routerLink]="['billing']"></tab>
</tabset>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Has anybody a solution for this? This problem should be quite common...

Answer (score 8):

I've solved this on my own this (easy) way completely without ng2-bootstrap, just native bootstrap CSS classes, `routerLink` and `routerLinkActive`:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link"
         routerLinkActive="active"
         [routerLink]="['info']">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link"
         routerLinkActive="active"
         [routerLink]="['users']">Users</a>
    </li>

    ...

  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the same. I think I will drop ng2-bootstrap from my app and use 'vanilla twitter bootstrap'.

Comment: We keep `ng2-bootstrap` in the project. There are a lot of valuable modules like AlertModule, DropdownModule, PaginationModule, TooltipModule, TypeaheadModule, ModalModule, DatepickerModule. And one can use the TabsModule for simple non-router navigation.

Answer (score 4):

Hey I have figured out a way to solve this.
try the following:

```
        <tabset class="nav nav-tabs">
            <tab>
                <template tabHeading>
                    <a class="routing_link" routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
                </template>
            </tab>
            <tab>
                <template tabHeading>
                    <a class="routing_link" routerLink="/execution">Execution</a>
                </template>

            </tab>
            <tab>
                <template tabHeading>
                    <a class="routing_link" routerLink="/history">History</a>
                </template>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
```

**Edit**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<tabset class="nav nav-tabs">
        <tab>
            <template tabHeading>
                <a class="routing_link" routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            </template>
        </tab>
        <tab>
            <template tabHeading>
                <a class="routing_link" routerLink="/execution">Execution</a>
            </template>
        </tab>
        <tab>
            <template tabHeading>
                <a class="routing_link" routerLink="/history">History</a>
            </template>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do you place the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`? Seams your code just renders the tab headers, or have I missed something?

Comment: My
   `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`  
is right underneath it. Please see update

Comment: I'll give it a try next time. Without seeing it in action - your solution seams not to mark the active tab when route changes, does it?

Comment: It will change. You can give a try with it. Once you click on it, the tab will become active.

Comment: When you click on it, then it will become active - that's clear, yes. But I suppose it won't become active when you route to the link.